# pymsql query on lambda makes the function run until timeout

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

I am connecting to an RDS MySQL instance from within an AWS lambda.
The connection does not return error, I edited the security group inbound rules to make it to every internet connection:

```
conn = pymysql.connect(
        host='@@@@@@@@@@@.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com',
        user='admin1', 
        password = "mypassword"
    )
    
mycursor = conn.cursor()
mycursor
```

So far the lambda works properly.

However, when trying to run the following code on the lambda, it will run until timeout:

```
mycursor.execute('SELECT * FROM db_test.customers')

Output: Task timed out after 15.02 seconds"
```

I already created the database and table from local, it works fine and the query is correct, so it is the .execute command that is breaking the lambda. How can I make it work?

Comment: How many rows are in the table? If there are many, it could simply need more time. Try `SELECT 42` instead just to test the connection.

Comment: I tried with several queries, the only one that seems to be working is mycursor.execute("SHOW DATABASES;"). For example mycursor.execute('CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS db_test') makes the function run until timeout.
Maybe using lambda to interact with RDS MySQL is a bad practice? I read aurora is the only one with a configured API for running SQL queries.

Comment: Accessing a database from an AWS Lambda function is a very common practice. It's just a matter of figuring out what is happening here. If you increase the timeout on the Lambda function (eg to 2 minutes), does it work any better?

Comment: I found out the problem. I had to add autocommit=True to pymysql.connect method: If I am correct (please correct me if i am wrong) I cannot stage changes on a lambda, so by committing them every single time the problem is solved. I can run several queries now.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, I need to add the autocommit=True to the connection method:

```
conn = pymysql.connect(
        host='@@@@@@@@@@@.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com',
        user='admin1', 
        password = "mypassword",
        autocommit=True
    )
```

In this way, no query breaks.

Comment: It is quite strange that failure to commit changes would cause the connection to timeout. However, if it has solved your problem, then it's good to know!